# Extension and spring boot configuration for cors fail

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I use spring boot 2.2 with angular 9.

I use cors extension in firefox and chrome

Also in spring boot i put

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
   }
}
```

I continue to have this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/credit/1/cancel'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

edit

tried

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.cors().and().build();
     }

     @Bean
     CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
         UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
         source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
         return source;
    }
}
```

just worst

Comment: "It does not have HTTP ok status." Is the HTTP server on port 8081 up and serving requests?

Comment: 8081 is my spring boot application and 4200 is nodejs

Comment: And I take it if you request the page directly (not cross domain), it responds with a 200 OK? What are the CORS headers set to? Also not sure what CORS plugin you use... but Chrome does not support CORS for localhost

Answer (score 0):

You should also check your Spring Security configuration. 
CORS should be enabled via `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()...
    }
}
```

More details in [Spring official documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)